# Inserting point into PostGIS?

Tags: postgis

I have created one table in my PostGIS nut I cannot insert point.

What is wrong with my query?

```
CREATE TABLE app ( 
  p_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY

);

SELECT AddGeometryColumn('app','the_geom','4326','POINT',2);

INSERT INTO app(p_id, the_geom) VALUES(2, POINT(-71.060316, 48.432044));
```

After the last query it shows some error..

```
ERROR:  column "the_geom" is of type geometry but expression is of type point
LINE 1: ...SERT INTO app(p_id, the_geom) VALUES(2, POINT(-71....
                                                             ^
HINT:  You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.


********** Error **********

ERROR: column "the_geom" is of type geometry but expression is of type point
SQL state: 42804
Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
Character: 53
```

I already check my PostGIS version.

```
SELECT PostGIS_full_version();
```

I got the following output..

```
"POSTGIS="1.5.3" GEOS="3.3.1-CAPI-1.7.1" PROJ="Rel. 4.7.1, 23 September 2009" LIBXML="2.7.3" USE_STATS"
```

Answer (score 104, accepted):

You are confusing [SQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL) and [WKT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text_representation_of_geometry) (well-known *text*). WKT is a like a geometry language to describe shapes, but it is not SQL, which is a language to query and manipulate databases. When working with WKT in an SQL query, it must be *text*, and not mixed-in with the SQL.

Your query works if you properly format the WKT (remove the ",") and set an SRID. For this method, [`ST_GeomFromText(wkt, srid)`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_GeomFromText.html) works well:

```
INSERT INTO app(p_id, the_geom)
VALUES(2, ST_GeomFromText('POINT(-71.060316 48.432044)', 4326));
```

If you have columns with numeric longitude/latitude, you can directly make a POINT geometry:

```
ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(long, lat), 4326);
```

Check out the other geometry constructors [in the manual](https://postgis.net/docs/reference.html#Geometry_Constructors).

---

For @vik86's request, `the_geom` can be updated in the table `app` from numeric columns `long` and `lat` using:

```
UPDATE app SET
  the_geom = ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(long, lat), 4326);
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on using this feature, "If you have columns with numeric longitude latitude, you can directly make a POINT geometry: ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(long, lat), 4326); " Right now I have a table with lat and long, to use the PostGIS api's I need it in the point format . Hence wanted to know how do i update the point column using this feature. Thanks
Vikram

Comment: The link to the documentation is broken. You can use this one instead: https://postgis.net/docs/ST_GeomFromText.html

Comment: @Akronix thanks, links updated for answer

Answer (score 3):

*If* you are working with a Java client then my advice is to use the binary types to transfer the data. From memory, I recorded a performance improvement of 10% when I did this change over the ST_AsEWKT method.