# Making POINT from longitude/latitude coordinates in existing table using PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, point, geometry, coordinates, table

I would like to [make a POINT using the longitude and latitude columns of an existing table](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/24487/12180). 
 Here's a link to the documentation of [ST_MakePoint](http://www.postgis.org/docs/ST_MakePoint.html).

Here's my table:

```
CREATE TABLE sysinst.bio (  
    oid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,  
    longitude FLOAT,  
    latitude FLOAT,  
        geom GEOMETRY(POINT, 26913)
);
```

Adding Geometry Column:

```
SELECT AddGeometryColumn ('sysinst', 'bio', 'geom', 26913, 'POINT', 2);
```

Here's my query:

```
UPDATE sysinst.bio SET geom = ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(longitude, latitude), 26913);
```

No returned error though the POINTS are wrongly plotted when viewed in QGIS.

For `(-97.5959, 21.1922)` , I recieve `(-109.4896, 0.0002)`

Any suggestions?

I'm open to doing this more efficiently if there's an easier way.

Comment: I'm not seeing the problem with the query. Perhaps you can try to diagnose the problem in parts - perhaps try to eliminate the QGIS part, and just use the command line for postgis?

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding, but you seem to be entering Longitude Latitude coordinates (-97, 21) in degrees,into a CRS that is UTM based, and uses meters. If you're declaring this as SRID 26918, then the long/lat values must be in that CRS. If the Long/Lat values are in degrees then you will need to create the geometry as ST_SetSRID(MakePoint(...),4326) then transform the layer to 26913

Comment: @Micha, your should add your comment as an answer. I expect the proper SRID will solve the OPs problem. It might also be helpful to include and example of how to add an [ST_Transform](http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/ST_Transform.html).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Maybe I'm not understanding, but you seem to be entering Longitude Latitude coordinates (-97, 21) in degrees,into a CRS that is UTM based, and uses meters. If you're declaring this as SRID 26918, then the long/lat values must be in that CRS. If the Long/Lat values are in degrees then you will need to create the geometry as ST_SetSRID(MakePoint(...),4326) then transform the layer to 26913. 
So, putting it all together, if you need to have the layer in 26913, but your longitude/latitude columns are in degrees, with CRS 4326, then

```
UPDATE sysinst.bio SET geom = ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(longitude, latitude), 4326),26913);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I should have thought about that before...