# Storing a point coordinate in PostGIS

Tags: postgis, postgresql, point, latitude-longitude

I'm finding a hard time storing a point coordinate as the location to a PostgreSQL using PostGIS:

I found this query, but I'm unable to understand what the SRID and CRS values specified in this [answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/54646/making-point-from-longitude-latitude-coordinates-in-existing-table-using-postgis) refers to.

```
UPDATE table_name SET geom = ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(longitude, latitude), 4326),26913);
```

Comment: The SRID of 26913 refers to [NAD83 UTM Zone 13N](https://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/26913/). Is your question about SRIDs in general, or about the specific choice of the OP in that question?

Answer (score 3):

In that example, the TYPE is Geometry which is a Point type and the SRID of the geom column is set as >> geom GEOMETRY(POINT, 26913).

So.....

ST_MakePoint(longitude, latitude) makes the point with the lat, long provided.

ST_SetSRID(XXXXXXX, 4326) sets the projection of the lat, long provided *4326* (WGS84).

ST_Transform(XXXXXXX,26913) transforms the projection to *26913*.  Which the geom column is set in.

More information can be found here.
https://postgis.net/docs/ST_MakePoint.html

Work these out from inside out and try to test it as a Select statement before commiting to the table.