# Manually add a new point to PostGIS table

Tags: qgis, postgis, postgresql, point

I did accidently delete a table row - or well, in fact a whole subway station.

My attempt to solve the problem was this PostGIS function:

```
ST_GeomFromText('POINT(coordinates)')
```

But then PostgreSQL started to complain about some SRID connection with the `spatial_ref_sys` table. What did I do wrong? Is it possible to add this through QGIS instead?

Comment: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/24486/how-to-insert-a-point-into-postgis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try INSERT INTO and use SRID parameter for the geometry

```
INSERT INTO your_table
col-1-value,...,col-n-value, (SELECT ST_GeomFromText('POINT(coordinates)', SRID))
```

where SRID is an id of your spatial reference system (4326 for example).

Also it is possible to add needed points using QGIS. Check corresponding section of [QGIS manual](http://www.qgis.org/en/documentation/manuals.html).

Comment: How do I know what SRID to use?

Comment: @Ivar, look in geometry_columns table.

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
ST_SetSRID(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(coordinates)'),4326)
```

instead. Replace 4326 with the correct code as necessary.