# Insert values in Postgresql in Java

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I try to insert same values in my table and I write this code:

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO points (gid, osm_id, name, type, geom) 
         VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?,ST_GeomFromText('POINT(?, ?)', 2100));";
         pst = con.prepareStatement(sql);
         pst.setInt(1, 40001);
         pst.setInt(2, 2);
         pst.setString(3, "General");
         pst.setString(4, "Heller");
         pst.setDouble(5, 69.6);
         pst.setDouble(6, 80.3);

         pst.executeUpdate();
```

but is show me an exception

> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The column index is out of range:
>   5, number of columns: 4.

If someone can help me.

Solved it by using:

`pst.setString(5,"POINT("+lat+" "+log+")" );`

```
"INSERT INTO points (gid, osm_id, name, type, geom)VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?,ST_GeomFromText(?, 2100));"
```

Comment: This is a JDBC issue -- The "?" is supposed to correspond to a *column* value, not as a generic substitution tool.  Instead, use String.format to format the WKT.

Comment: I try to pass as two double number

Comment: Right, but that's not how that functionality is *supposed* to work.

Comment: If `lat` is latitude and `log` is longitude, you have to swap them, since the correct axis order for PostGIS is POINT(log lat)

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
'POINT(?, ?)'
```

is within a literal string, so placeholders are not interpreted.

You must instead keep the placeholders outside a literal and use concatenation or function call syntax.

In this case there's actually a `point(x,y)` function, so you can just write:

```
POINT(?,?)
```

without the single quotes, but if that weren't the case and you needed to compose a value you'd instead concatenate:

```
'POINT('||?||','||?||')'
```

or replace the whole thing with a single parameter:

```
?
```

and send the string `POINT(blah,blah)`, composed client-side, to the server.

Answer (score 1):

This is sort-of the same answer [as this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/24487/1872), except adapted a bit more for your situation. Basically, you are mixing SQL parameters in WKT. Since you have numeric data, you shouldn't be making WKT anyway, and directly make a point instead.

```java
String sql = "INSERT INTO points (gid, osm_id, name, type, geom) "
           + "VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(?, ?), 2100));";
pst = con.prepareStatement(sql);
pst.setInt(1, 40001);
pst.setInt(2, 2);
pst.setString(3, "General");
pst.setString(4, "Heller");
pst.setDouble(5, 69.6); // longitude
pst.setDouble(6, 80.3); // latitude
pst.executeUpdate();
```

Also, if your `gid` column is a serial type, you should remove it here and let the database assign it.