# Insert point into point column in postgres/postgis

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I'm trying to insert point data in my database, but it tells me the data types aren't correct (and *I think* they are). Here's my table:

```
 Column      |  Type
 ------------+----------
 coordinates | point
```

And my query:

```
INSERT INTO points(coordinates) VALUES (ST_GeomFromText('POINT(10.809003 54.097834)',4326));
ERROR:  column "coordinates" is of type point but expression is of type geometry
LINE 1: INSERT INTO points(coordinates) VALUES (ST_GeomFromText('POI...
                                                ^
HINT:  You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
```

I don't quite get what is wrong (using the same as a select works). I get the same with `LINESTRING` and `POINT`, and my syntax seems to be the same as [How to insert a point into postgis?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/24486)

---

I partially made it work with help from @amball by dropping the table and re-making it. The insert worked, but not I have this:

```
gisdb=# INSERT INTO points(coordinates) VALUES (ST_GeomFromText('POINT(10.809003 54.097834)',4326));
INSERT 0 1
gisdb=# select * from points;
 id |                    coordinates
----+----------------------------------------------------
  1 | 0101000020E610000056BB26A4359E2540EB3713D3850C4B40
(1 row)
```

I don't know what happened with the coordinates (they are supposed to be `10.809003 54.097834` or something similar.

Here's the table info, which looks better, by the way:

```
   Column    |         Type         |                      Modifiers                      | Storage | Stats target | Description
-------------+----------------------+-----------------------------------------------------+---------+--------------+-------------
 id          | integer              | not null default nextval('points_id_seq'::regclass) | plain   |              |
 coordinates | geometry(Point,4326) |                                                     | main    |              |
```

Comment: How did you create your column "coordinates"? If you created it with SELECT AddGeometryColumn('points','coordinates','4326','POINT',2); your geometry column should have type geometry(Point, 4326)

Comment: @amball If I remember correctly, I just created the new table putting `POINT` as data, or something similar.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You've succeeded! The strange text you're seeing - `0101000020E610000056BB26A4359E2540EB3713D3850C4B40`
... is the point you made before, represented as 'well known binary' (WKB).

To see it in something more human-readable (Well Known Text):

```
SELECT st_asewkt('0101000020E610000056BB26A4359E2540EB3713D3850C4B40')
```

giving you:

```
SRID=4326;POINT(10.809003 54.097834)
```

Comment: Yes, it does! Thank you very much. I thought it would be stored like `10.809003 54.097834` and got me really confused haha