# Updating table with GeometryFromText of PostGIS

Tags: postgis, update

I'm trying to update a column public_geometry in a table  by creating a point from longitude and latitude cols from the same table. The database is PostgreSQL with Pgadmin as program to handle the databasse:

```
 UPDATE sirene_test.etablisssement_actif
SET geom=ST_GeometryFromText('POINT('|| latitude  ||' '|| longitude ||')', 4326);
```

I got this Error :

```
ERREUR:  parse error - invalid geometry
HINT:  "POINT( )" <-- parse error at position 9 within geometry
********** Erreur **********

ERREUR: parse error - invalid geometry
État SQL :XX000
Astuce : "POINT( )" <-- parse error at position 9 within geometry
```

Comment: What do you get by `select 'POINT('|| latitude  ||' '|| longitude ||')' from sirene_test.etablisssement_actif limit 3`?

Comment: I got a column with point( logitude , latitude ) . or empty !
"POINT(48.934248 2.258772)"
"POINT(50.444846 2.611103)"
"POINT(4.931439 -52.317082)"
"POINT( )"

Comment: Filter the empty ones out `where latitude is not null and longitude is not null`.

Comment: Well-Known Text uses coordinate order {longitude,latitude}, and the canonical way to do this is `ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(longitude,latitude),4326)`

Comment: See https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/24486/inserting-point-into-postgis

Comment: In order to prevent experts from guessing what is wrong with your data, please provide a part of it by clicking on the download link, and maybe you will be explained and helped to find the right solution...

Comment: Maybe the solution looks like this: UPDATE sirene_test.etablisssement_actif SET geom = ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(longitude, latitude), 4326) WHERE ST_GeometryType(geom)='ST_Point';