# Inserting X,Y to Geometry in Spring Boot and PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, java

I use @query to Insert X,Y to Geometry in PostgreSQL.

```
@Modifying
@Query(value = " insert into mypoints (name,geom) values (:name,SRID=4326;POINT(:x :y))", nativeQuery = true)
@Transactional
void addSPCTY(@Param("name") String ten,@Param("x") String x,@Param("y") String y);
```

Right now it ends up with an error

> Error in Java: `org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax
>   error near ;`

Comment: Shouldnt `SRID=4326;POINT(:x :y)` be more like `ST_GeomFromText('POINT(-71.060316 48.432044)', 4326))` (I dont know java). See: [Inserting point into PostGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/24486/inserting-point-into-postgis)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Inserting point into PostGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/24486/inserting-point-into-postgis)

Comment: Tks . But it error: ERROR: parse error - invalid geometry
  Hint: "POINT(:x" <-- parse error at position 8 within geometry